# How is the partition type GUID supposed to be interpreted?

Tags: guid-partition-table

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs) and various other sources, the partition type GUID for a BIOS boot partition is `21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649`. This is supposed to represent `Hah!IdontneedEFI`.

The first line is how it's stored on disk, the second line contains the ASCII values:

```
48 61 68 21 49 64 6F 6E 74 4E 65 65 64 45 46 49
H  a  h  !  I  d  o  n  t  N  e  e  d  E  F  I
```

If we take the previously mentioned GUID, we get:

```
21 68 61 48 64 49 6E 6F 74 4E 65 65 64 45 46 49
!  h  a  H  d  I  n  o  t  N  e  e  d  E  F  I
```

Why the difference?

Comment: GUID has an [internal structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931(v=vs.85).aspx), uint + ushort + ushort + byte[8].  You are looking at a little-endian machine.

Comment: @HansPassant I figured endianness had something to do with it, didn't know about that internal structure. Want to post an answer? Otherwise I can post one.

Comment: Nevermind, found a duplicate :)